# Howto avoid MSIE scrolling a table with overflow: hidden;

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

The last column of a table is intentionally clipped without scrollbars, by using

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the Tables container.
If I enter the columns input field by pressing Tab, on MSIE it scrolls the focused column into the viewport. I would like to turn this feature off and make it similar to FF where it stays fixed.

Edit: I just recognized that FF is doing the same if the column is fully invisible, MSIE will do it even if the column is partially clipped.

Edit: Any javascript solution would be welcome. Something like 'preventdefault' but i have no idea on what event to hook.

```css
#Container {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Tab</th>
        <td>
          <input type='text' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you having this problem in?

Comment: @Bojangles i've tried IE11 on Win7 with Browserstack

Comment: This is standard behaviour for a browser to make the element fully visible when it receives the focus. And you cannot prevent the default behaviour either in the [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) or [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin) events. So your best chance would be to save the scroll positions before the focus event and to restore it afterwards using in JS (with possible flickering).

Comment: Hi @GyumFox, would 'saving the scroll position' be achieved with jQuery offset().left? I guess that the easiest way to restore the position would than be jquery offset as well. Any better idea?

Comment: Not sure in jQuery. In pure JS, you're looking at scrollLeft and scrollTop if the element with the scrollbar isn't the page itself (else you might need a bit of cross browser magic such as: window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || element.scrollTop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behaviour of the browser to bring the `input` into view when focussing (actually when typing), as pointed out by @GyumFox.

What you can do is, either reset the scroll or disable the `input`s that are out of bounds of your table, using Javascript.

**Option 1:** (*Reset the scroll*)

This will work fine in Chrome and Firefox but give you a flicker in IE.

*Fiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/eg0ae5cg/1/*

*Snippet 1:*

```js
$("#Container").on("scroll", function() {
    $(this).scrollLeft(0);
});
```

```css
#Container {
    table-layout: fixed; width: 400px; overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Tab</th>
        <td><input type='text' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Option 2**: (*Disable the out-of-bound inputs*)

This is a crude example. You need to fine-tune this as required.

*Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/pkb2t127/1/ *

*Snippet 2:*

```js
var $tab = $("#Container"), 
    $txt = $tab.find("input"),
    w = $tab.width();

$txt.each(function() {
    var lft = $(this).position().left, 
        rgt = lft + $(this).width();
    
    if (rgt >= w) { $(this).prop("disabled", true); }
})
```

```css
#Container {
    table-layout: fixed; width: 400px; overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Tab</th>
        <td><input type='text' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Instead of `disabled` property, you could use the `readonly` property to keep the input value in the form post.

Comment: Thanks, the on-scroll event plus resetting scroll-left was somehow what i am looking for. The first solution works for my case.

Comment: Yes, the first solution is the one I was thinking of. Depending on the structure of your page, you might consider saving the scroll position of all the parents then restore all of them after focus (that's if your table is contained into other scrollable elements)